# Thingsboard: JSON parse error when reading MQTT timestamp

Tags: json, timestamp, mqtt, rules, thingsboard

I get this MQTT payload from a device: (and I can't change how the device sends it)

{t:2021-11-08T16:17:15Z,10:99,14:24,55:20.85,56:64.38,53:36.00}

This is the timestamp: t:2021-11-08T16:17:15Z
I know that TB expects the UNIX style timestamp, and I expected to change this timestamp into the UNIX style in a transform node in the Rule Chain.

But, it never gets there because I believe that TB parses it before getting to the Rule Chain, and throughs an exception and rejects the readings.

How can I prevent TB to do that early parsing so I can get to the value and change it to the expected ts format? Is there a configuration or any other way besides forking the project and rewriting the parser?

Thank you!

Here is the error I get from the logs:

```
2021-11-08 23:39:25,124 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-5] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [f5a4a965-8177-4daf-9a56-9197a55fab7d] Processing connect msg for client: xxxx!
2021-11-08 23:39:25,125 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-5] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [f5a4a965-8177-4daf-9a56-9197a55fab7d] Processing connect msg for client with user name: null!
2021-11-08 23:39:25,167 [DefaultTransportService-18-34] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [f5a4a965-8177-4daf-9a56-9197a55fab7d] Client connected!
2021-11-08 23:39:25,183 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-5] WARN  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [f5a4a965-8177-4daf-9a56-9197a55fab7d] Failed to process publish msg [device/lre/readings][1]
org.thingsboard.server.common.transport.adaptor.AdaptorException: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 18 path $.t
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.adaptors.JsonMqttAdaptor.convertToPostTelemetry(JsonMqttAdaptor.java:67)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.processDevicePublish(MqttTransportHandler.java:343)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.processPublish(MqttTransportHandler.java:298)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.processRegularSessionMsg(MqttTransportHandler.java:255)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.lambda$processMsgQueue$0(MqttTransportHandler.java:249)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.session.DeviceSessionCtx.tryProcessQueuedMsgs(DeviceSessionCtx.java:181)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.processMsgQueue(MqttTransportHandler.java:249)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.enqueueRegularSessionMsg(MqttTransportHandler.java:241)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.processMqttMsg(MqttTransportHandler.java:183)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler.channelRead(MqttTransportHandler.java:156)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 18 path $.t
        at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:84)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:59)
        at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:45)
        at org.thingsboard.server.transport.mqtt.adaptors.JsonMqttAdaptor.convertToPostTelemetry(JsonMqttAdaptor.java:65)
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 18 path $.t
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1567)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:495)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.hasNext(JsonReader.java:418)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:742)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$29.read(TypeAdapters.java:718)
        at com.google.gson.internal.Streams.parse(Streams.java:48)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
2021-11-08 23:39:25,183 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-5] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [f5a4a965-8177-4daf-9a56-9197a55fab7d] Closing current session due to invalid publish msg [device/lre/readings][1]
2021-11-08 23:39:25,184 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-5] INFO  o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [f5a4a965-8177-4daf-9a56-9197a55fab7d] Client disconnected!
2021-11-08 23:39:28,533 [queue-scheduler-11-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.q.u.DefaultTbApiUsageClient - Reporting API usage statistics for 3 tenants and customers
2021-11-08 23:39:29,253 [sql-log-1-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-0 [TS] queueSize [0] totalAdded [6] totalSaved [6] totalFailed [0]
2021-11-08 23:39:29,254 [sql-log-1-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-2 [TS] queueSize [0] totalAdded [90] totalSaved [90] totalFailed [0]
2021-11-08 23:39:29,351 [sql-log-1-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-0 [TS Latest] queueSize [0] totalAdded [6] totalSaved [6] totalFailed [0]
2021-11-08 23:39:29,351 [sql-log-1-thread-1] INFO  o.t.s.dao.sql.TbSqlBlockingQueue - Queue-2 [TS Latest] queueSize [0] totalAdded [90] totalSaved [90] totalFailed [0]
2021-11-08 23:39:29,530 [TB-Scheduling-6] INFO  o.t.server.actors.ActorSystemContext - Rule Engine JS Invoke Stats: requests [6] responses [3] failures [0]
2021-11-08 23:39:29,612 [TB-Scheduling-5] INFO  o.t.s.s.s.DefaultTbEntityDataSubscriptionService - Stats: regularQueryInvocationCnt = [1], regularQueryInvocationTime = [2], dynamicQueryCnt = [3] dynamicQueryInvocationCnt = [1], dynamicQueryInvocationTime = [2], alarmQueryInvocationCnt = [0], alarmQueryInvocationTime = [0]
```

Comment: Are you using Professional Edition or Community Edition. Also, where are you seeing these error logs, on an integration, data converter, or rule chain node.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON syntax: `{t:2021-11-08T16:17:15Z,10:99,14:24,55:20.85,56:64.38,53:36.00}`. According to the standard, there should be quotation marks, like `{"t":"2021-…"}`.

The error may be somehow related to invalid format, considering that "line 1 column 18" points at second ':', which is a part of node value int his case, but could be treated as name-value separator by your app.

Comment: The "right" answer here is fix the device to send properly formated JSON, you've not said why you think this isn't possible

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I'm using Community Edition.  Regarding the format I agree, but this is not the first not valid format I've seen that is sent by a device. I've tried issuing the valid double-quoted format using mosquitto_pub, and it doesn't work either. It only works when I single quote it, because then it takes it as a string and it doesn't parse what is inside the single quotes. Regarding the device, I have no access to it or its firmware, that is why I can't fix it.

Comment: I'm sure the maker can (although I don't know if he would like to), but I was hoping to be able to handle deviations from the standards at my gate, and not having to go to each provider to make them change thing to what I can handle. That's why I wanted to know if there was a way to do the whole parsing manually inside the TB rule engine. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I left something unanswered from Jackson's question, the logs I showed are from /var/log/thingsboard. In the TB GUI there are no visible errors, it just does not ingest the readings.